# I used Interactive Picture jQuery and how do I link the box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, interactive

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $( "#iPicture6" ).iPicture({
        animation: true,
        animationBg: "bgblack",
        animationType: "ltr-slide",
        pictures: ["picture1","picture2","picture3","picture4","picture5"],
        button: "moreblack",
        moreInfos: {"picture1":[{"id":"tooltip1","descr":"Looking at Stars", "top":"200px","left":"103px"},{"id":"tooltip2","descr":"sofa: 199$","top":"346px","left":"483px"},{"id":"tooltip3","descr":"silver candle: 2.99$","top":"461px","left":"556px"}],
```

I have this code when I put in the javascript for INteractive picture jquery, I was wondering how can I go on about hyperlinking each button/box?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I know I'm getting down for this, any pointers?

Comment: any help would be great!

Comment: Your question is valid, so I've voted up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
moreInfos: {
  "picture1": [
    {
      "id":"tooltip1",
      "descr":"<a href='http://www.google.com'>furniture: 299$</a>",
      "top":"185px",
      "left":"393px"
    }
    // And So on....
```

You'll see that you'll have a hyperlink in the description of your button/box.

Comment: cheers for this, for beginners like me, this forum is a great help to expand my knowledge in HTML & Javascript :)